# how to validate the input while entering the data using Jquery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to validate the input while entering the data using Jquery event?

```
 $("#lname").blur(function() {
        if ($("#lname").val().trim().match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)) {
            $("#lname").css({"border":"1px solid #cecece"});
            $("#error_lname").css("display","none");
        }
        else{
            $("#error_lname").css("display","block");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate as the user types, use the `input` event instead of `blur`:

```
$("#lname").on('input', function() {
    if ($("#lname").val().trim().match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)) {
        $("#lname").css({"border":"1px solid #cecece"});
        $("#error_lname").css("display","none");
    }
    else{
        $("#error_lname").css("display","block");

    }
});
```

You should however note that to follow best practices you should avoid using `css()` and instead add/remove a class that's defined in an external stylesheet, something like this:

```
$("#lname").on('input', function() { 
    var $el = $(this);
    var valid = $el.val().trim().match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/);
    $el.toggleClass('invalid', !valid);
    $el.next('.error-msg').toggle(!valid);
});
```

```css
.invalid { border: 1px solid #CECECE; }
```

Note that the above is assuming the `input` you're validating has a following sibling which is the error message which has the class of `.error-msg`. Organising the logic in this way means that the validation logic can easily be genericised - instead of being tied to each control due to the `#error_lname` selector.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Rory is perfect I just want to add that you can also use **[onkeyup](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)** event also to get the same effect.

```js
$("#lname").on('keyup', function() { 
    var $el = $(this);
    var valid = $el.val().trim().match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/);
    $el.toggleClass('invalid', !valid);
    $el.next('.error-msg').toggle(!valid);
});
```

```css
.error-msg{
  display:none;
  color:red;
}

.invalid{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname">
<span class="error-msg">Error message here ...</span>
```

Comment: Just be aware that this won't fire if pasted in via the mouse.

Comment: Yes that's true and I just realize it when I just tested it. Thanks I've learned also something new :)